# bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js missing from visual studio 2015 project 3.3.6

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I created a new project in VisualStudio 2015 and added Bootstrap 3.3.6 via nuGet to the project and found that bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js are no where in the project (even though it is installed).
I can put this in manually to fix, but was wondering if the NuGet package for this version is buggy (would like to get it to work properly).
Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening & what I may be missing or how to fix?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the package. I can install 3.3.5 fine - css & script is there. Once I update to 3.3.6, the files disappear again.

Comment: Have you tried to show all files? Maybe it is hidden .

Comment: Yes. It's very odd. Just to make sure I wasn't crazy, I ran a search in the folder.

Comment: Looks like 3.3.5 is working just fine. I'll just keep using it for now.

Comment: Ok sounds good to me .

Comment: @DaveN - post this as answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and removed all packages requiring BootStrap prerequisite, then the last version of it. Saved the project. Rebooted VS. Then added version 3.3.6 back and, voila, the files are where they should be.